# Realm getinstance method is extremely slow in android api 28

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am developing an android application which uses Realm as an offline database, opening the app for the first time takes a lot of time, almost **3-4 seconds** and inspecting the things under the hood through android **strict mode** I came out to know that **Realm getinstance()** method itself is taking **1-2 seconds.**

Is there any workaround this problem? It's extremely slow..